# npm config file not reading environment variables

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

I'm not able to get my project .npmrc file to recognize any of the environment variables set at three different scopes (project, user, global).

The only way I'm able to install a private module is by hardcoding the api key into the .npmrc file, which is obviously unacceptable since .npmrc is watched by git.

I've tried creating environment variables as the [`npm-config` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc#files) suggest, i.e.:

- in a project `.env` file, where both a `.npmrc` file and a `.env` file are siblings of `package.json`, i.e.: `fontawesome_pro_token=ABC123`
- in a user config file, i.e.: `$ npm set fontawesome_pro_token ABC123`
- in a global config file, i.e.: `$ npm set fontawesome_pro_token ABC123 --global`

When I reference the env variable in the project `.npmrc` file, i.e.:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${fontawesome_pro_token}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${fontawesome_pro_token}
```

When I remove the curly braces around the variable name (as [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48728994/2145103) suggests), I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized
```

**Any advice on how to config npm to read env variables?**

---

**Incidentally** -- if deploying private modules to Netlify, Netlify expects the .npmrc file to use the curly braces for env var syntax, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/biilmann/0b2250095eedc188d0c9). I can confirm that using the curly brace syntax in a git watched npmrc file, along with [setting a build env var](https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#build-environment-variables) in the netlify project admin dashboard, indeed works.

Answer (score 2):

Use your env vars without curly braces like:

```
$fontawesome_pro_token
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your casing to UPPERCASE when refer to your .env file or handle environment variables

`@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/`
`//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=${FONTAWESOME_PRO_TOKEN}`